# yii tokeninput extension cursor focus on wrong place after same match?

Tags: yii, jquery-tokeninput, yii-extensions

I am having problem with yii tokeninput extension. When i search name it gives the user list and if i select any name and if that name is also selected previous than the cursor point after the selected item, it does not point at the end of all the the item in the input box.

I am using this configuration.

```
$this->widget('ext.tokeninput.TokenInput', array(
       'model' => $model,
       'attribute' => 'USER_ID',
       'url'=>$this->createUrl('user/searchUserNames'),
       'options' => array(
           'allowCreation' => false,
           'preventDuplicates' => true,
          // 'resultsFormatter' => 'js:function(item){ return “<li><p>” + item.name + “</p></li>” }',
           'theme' => 'facebook',
            //'hintText' => 'Type',
            'prePopulate' => $prePopulate,
            'processPrePopulate' => $processPrePopulate,

       )
   ));
```

I have also lookout at the examples but does not find the solution. can any one help me ?
[Loopj: jquery token input demo](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/demo.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    plz comment the line number 509 in **jquery.tokeninput.js** 
    input_token.insertAfter(found_existing_token);
    that line insert cursor after that selected item so if you comment 
    this line cursor is at the end of all names
```

Comment: It solved 50% of the problem but it still point to the same place when we start typing to it the input box.

Comment: Add these lines below that commented lines
found_existing_token.addClass(settings.classes.selectedToken);
input_box.val("");

Comment: There is one more issue,if we select the existed token and then add new name then the existed token remains selected.